# How to download file in browser using spring mvc?

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc

I have file on the server & that I want to download on my machine using browser. But I am not getting an option from browser to download the file.

My code is

JSP

```
<div id="jqgrid">
    <table id="grid"></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
jq("#grid").jqGrid({
    ....

    onCellSelect: function(rowid, index, contents, event) {
    ...
       var fileName = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getCell',rowid,'fileName');
       $scope.downloadFile(fileName);
    }
});


$scope.downloadFile = function(fileName) {
    $http({
        url: "logreport/downLoadFile", 
        method: "GET",
        params: {"fileName": fileName}
     });
};
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downLoadFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void downLoadFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        String fileName = request.getParameter("fileName");
        File file = new File(filePath +"//"+fileName);
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

        response.setContentType("application/xlsx");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName+".xlsx"); 


        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am not getting any exception but not sure why browser dialog is not opening to download the file. Also where is it exactly downloading the file?

Comment: so have you tried to debug it? without any concrete errors all we can do is guess what is happening.

Comment: You cannot download a file through a javascript ajax request.

Comment: Are you sure that you can retrieve `fileName` in controller?

Comment: @suninsky Yes, I am getting the fileName.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis why is it not possible? I am getting the file name in controller.

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood I debug the code & code is working fine cz if I set the destination in outputstream then I could see the file being copied there.

Answer (score 3):

@SotiriosDelimanolis was right. File download is not possible using ajax request.
Simply use `'window.location'`.

```
$scope.downloadFile = function(fileName) {
    window.location.href = 'logreport/downLoadFile?fileName=asdad1';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have enough credit to give a comment so wiritting  here.. Thanks user1298426. I was strugling  like anything for this. I was trying with AJAX. With window.location.href, I can download file in browser...

MY javascript code is as follows:

```
jQuery('#exportToZip').click(function() {
    window.location.href = '*****';
});
```

*****: is the url mapping that I have in controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/****")
@ResponseBody
public void downloadRequesthandler(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
    String status;
    try {
        filedownloader.doGet(request, response); 
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        status="servlet Exception occured";
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        status="IO Exception occured";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //return status;
}

public void  doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();

    // construct the complete absolute path of the file
    File downloadFile = new File(filePath);
    System.out.println("downloadFile path: "+ filePath);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);

    // get MIME type of the file
    String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fullPath);
    if (mimeType == null) {
        // set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
        mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
    }
    System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);
    response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());

    // set headers for the response
    String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
    String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",downloadFile.getName());
    response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    System.out.println("buffer: "+ buffer.length);
    int bytesRead = -1;

    // write bytes read from the input stream into the output stream
    //be carefull in this step. "writebeyondcontentlength" and "response already committed"  error is very common here
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer))!=-1  ) {

        outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    inputStream.close();
    outStream.close();
}
```

Trying to download file with ajax is a blunder....

cheers......

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using IOUtils copy method

```
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(in, out);
```

You can use following :

```
 ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

 byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
 out.write(bytes);



 out.close();
 out.flush();
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: It is not opening the browser window to download the file.

Comment: Yes but it pretty much does the same thing. It does not open download prompt in the browser.